# A proof without Sylow/Cauchy that a centerless $G$ with $|G|=p^\alpha q$ ($p,q$ distinct primes, $\alpha\ge 1$) has a subgroup of order $q$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I managed to prove without Sylow/Cauchy that a centerless $G$ with $|G|=p^\alpha q$ ($p,q$ distinct primes, $\alpha\ge 1$) has a subgroup of order $p^\alpha$, but I'm struggling with $q$'s case. My proof goes as follows.

The nontrivial elements of $G$ must have centralizer of order either $p^\beta$, for some $1\le\beta\le\alpha$, or $p^\gamma q$, for some $0\le\gamma<\alpha$. Therefore, the class equation yields:
$$p^\alpha q=1+\sum_i p^{\alpha-\beta_i}q+\sum_j p^{\alpha-\gamma_j} \tag 1$$
Because of $\alpha-\gamma_j>0$ for every $j$, from $(1)$ follows:
$$p\mid 1+\sum_i p^{\alpha-\beta_i}q$$
whence $\beta_i=\alpha$ for some $i$ (because $p\nmid 1$). Therefore, there are centralizers of order $p^\alpha$ (and hence, incidentally, there are $k$ conjugacy classes of size $q$, for some $1\le k< p^\alpha$).

I expected this approach to just as readily show that $G$ has a subgroup/element of the order $q$, but so far unsuccessfully. Can you see how does this follow from $(1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can drop the centerless condition. We need to show there is an element of order multiple of $q$, we can do it by induction over $\alpha$. When $\alpha = 0$ it's easy.

We use your equation and get there is a non-identity element $x$ with centralizer of order $p^bq$, if $x$ has order multiple of $q$ we are done. If not we can look at $C_G(x)/\langle x \rangle$, by induction there is a coset with order multiple of $q$, and any element in that coset has order multiple of $q$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get some points: 1) "We can drop the centerless condition" and "we use your equation" are incompatibile, aren't they? 2) Why proving that there is an element of order multiple of $q$ does prove that there is an element of order $q$?

Comment: For 1), you can still use your equation, you just don't know how many summands are $1$, but that doesn't matter, there still has to be another summand that isn't a multiple of $q$, and this means a centralizer of order multiple of $q$. And for 2), if you have an element $x$ of order $qd$ then $x^d$ has order $q$.

Comment: It seems what I did is just a common inductive proof of cauchy's theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory) . I was more familiarized with the second proof.